# Translate Prototype into jQuery?

Tags: jquery, http-headers, prototypejs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Accessing HTTP Headers in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-http-headers-in-javascript)

How would this translate this PrototypeJS code into jQuery?

```
 etag = response.getHeader("Etag") || 0;
 lm = response.getHeader("Last-Modified") ||
      'Thu, 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT';
```

Comment: Depends on what is `response` is. What is it? You are likely looking for the `jqXHR` object: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR.

Comment: Its nginx: http://www.brentsowers.com/2011/06/http-long-polling-aka-comet-with-nginx.html

Comment: Looks like you want to access HTTP headers in JS, which I found using [this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=javascript+http+headers).

Comment: @Laine: I rather meant what object it is. Seems to be `Ajax.Response`: http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/ajax/Ajax/Response/index.html.

Comment: Ah first this has to be converted to jQuery also: var txt = response.responseText.stripScripts().stripTags();

Comment: How about reading the jQuery's `$.ajax` documentation (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and showing what you got so far? SO is not a free code translation service.

Comment: OP, you are expected to do your own research first before asking here, including understanding your own question. Just fyi.